# Como alterar a cor do DropDownList da Kendo UI conforme a variável de Status?

Tags: css, kendo-ui, dropdown

Alguém sabe me dizer se tem como mudar a cor da DropDownList da Kendo conforme uma variável de Status?

Por exemplo:

Caso o usuário esteja Ativo -> Assume a cor Verde

Caso o usuário esteja Inativo -> Assume a cor Vermelho

Caso não seja possível alterar a cor, pode ser um modo de colocar um ícone diferente, ou algum tipo de identificador por registro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom pessoal... procurei em diversos locais e não consegui trocar a cor da dropdownlist, mas consegui montar com ícones.... Segue o código para montar a DropDownList:

```
 var cliente = $("#cboCliente").kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: true,
    filter: "contains",
    dataTextField: "Nome",
    dataValueField: "Id",
    dataSource: {
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
          read: { url: urlBase + "/principal.php?ACAO=ComboClientes", dataType: "json", type: "POST", data: { MODULO: "Seguranca", TELA:"ClonarUsuario"} },
        },requestStart: function (e) {
           $(".clCarregando").show();
        },
        requestEnd: function (e) {
          $(".clCarregando").hide();
        }
    },
    valueTemplate: '<img class="selected-value" src="Imagens/#:Ativo#.png" style="width: 25px; vertical-align: middle;"/><span> &nbsp; #:Nome#</span>',
    template: kendo.template('<img class="selected-value" src="Imagens/#:Ativo#.png" style="width: 25px; vertical-align: middle;"/><span>  &nbsp; #:Nome#</span>'), });
```

O "Ativo" e que eu chamo no valueTemplate e no template vem do meu banco de dados, assim ele podem ser preenchidos com 0 ou 1, visto que o campo é bit. Criei duas imagens para ativo e inativo e dei a elas o nome de 0 e 1. Assim quando chamado ele vai carregar a imagem correspondente.